# Running ALSA latency benchmark on Android

Tags: android, audio, alsa, cyanogenmod, low-latency

I'm trying to benchmark ALSA's latency on Android using their latency.c micro-benchmark application ([ALSA's latency microbenchmark](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2latency_8c-example.html)). However, the latency application always fails to open any audio device on the device (both default and other options).

Output on running latency:

```
latency -P "hw:0,0" -C "hw:0,0" -r 44100 -m 128 -M 128 -p -s 1       <
WARNING: linker: ./latency: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x505
WARNING: linker: ./latency: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0xd3c
WARNING: linker: ./latency: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
Scheduler set to Round Robin with priority 99...
Playback device is hw:0,0
Capture device is hw:0,0
Parameters are 44100Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels, non-blocking mode
Poll mode: yes
Loop limit is 44100 frames, minimum latency = 128, maximum latency = 128
Playback open error: Invalid argument
```

I tried this on a bunch of other audio devices like hw:0,27 based on the numbers I received from `./aplay -L`

```
latency -P "hw:0,27" -C "hw:0,0" -r 44100 -m 128 -M 128 -p -s 1       <
WARNING: linker: ./latency: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x505
WARNING: linker: ./latency: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0xd3c
WARNING: linker: ./latency: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
Scheduler set to Round Robin with priority 99...
Playback device is hw:0,27
Capture device is hw:0,0
Parameters are 44100Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels, non-blocking mode
Poll mode: yes
Loop limit is 44100 frames, minimum latency = 128, maximum latency = 128
Record open error: Invalid argument
```

How do I get this application to run on the device and provide me a latency output value? I know that audio works on this device since I can use the built-in audio player to play .wav files. It doesn't seem to work with my compiled version of aplay (gives the same Playback open error).

On another note, what is the correct way to find out which audio device corresponds to the headset and/or the speaker/microphone? I've currently been trying to find these with trial and error.

Some details about the platform:

```
Unlocked Motorola Moto G LTE (codename peregrine)
OS: Cyanogenmod 12.1 with root privileges (based on Android 5.1 Lollipop)
Kernel: Linux localhost 3.4.42-g832c593 #1 SMP PREEMPT armv7l GNU/Linux
ALSA-lib & ALSA-utils: 1.1.0
```

**EDIT**

Output of `$ arecord -l`

```
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 0: MultiMedia1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 1: MultiMedia2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 2: CS-Voice (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 3: VoIP (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 5: SLIMBUS_0 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 6: INT_FM Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 8: AFE-PROXY TX msm-stub-tx-8 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 10: AUXPCM Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 11: SLIMBUS_1 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 12: SLIMBUS_3 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 13: SLIMBUS_4 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 14: Voice2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 15: MultiMedia5 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 16: MultiMedia9 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 17: VoLTE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 18: QCHAT (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 19: Listen Audio Service (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 20: COMPR8 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 22: (Internal BT-SCO Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 24: (Internal FM Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 26: (AFE Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 28: (AUX PCM Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 29: (AUX PCM Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 30: (Voice Uplink Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 31: (Voice Downlink Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 35: (Slimbus Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 37: (Slimbus1 Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 39: (Slimbus3 Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 41: (Slimbus4 Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 42: (Slimbus5 Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `$aplay -l`

```
WARNING: linker: ./aplay: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x1d20
WARNING: linker: ./aplay: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x1
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 0: MultiMedia1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 1: MultiMedia2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 2: CS-Voice (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 3: VoIP (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 4: LPA (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 5: SLIMBUS_0 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 6: INT_FM Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 7: AFE-PROXY RX msm-stub-rx-7 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 9: (COMPR) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 10: AUXPCM Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 11: SLIMBUS_1 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 12: SLIMBUS_3 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 13: SLIMBUS_4 Hostless (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 14: Voice2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 15: MultiMedia5 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 16: MultiMedia9 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 17: VoLTE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 18: QCHAT (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 20: COMPR8 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 21: (Internal BT-SCO Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 23: (Internal FM Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 25: (AFE Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 27: HDMI_RX_HOSTLESS (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 28: (AUX PCM Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 29: (AUX PCM Capture) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 32: (Voice Farend Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 33: (Voice2 Farend Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 34: (Slimbus Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 36: (Slimbus1 Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 38: (Slimbus3 Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: msm8226tapan930 [msm8226-tapan9302-snd-card], device 40: (Slimbus4 Playback) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: This is very hardware dependent. Show the output of `aplay -l` and `arecord -l`.

Comment: I added my output from `aplay -l` & `arecord -l` to the end of the question

Comment: That's an interesting piece of hardware. I'd guess you have to configure the device with some mixer controls to route the captured data to the correct device, whatever it is.

Comment: @CL: It's a motorola android phone. I'm relatively new to ALSA setup, especially when it goes wrong.Do you know a place where I can read about the mixer controls and how it works?

Comment: That's hardware dependent, and probably not documented anywhere.

Comment: Any general hints on how I can go about approaching it?I know the default audio player successfully manages to play sound but I can't seem to even when referring to the same devices. I ran strace on the audio server to make sure I was looking at the right device files in /dev